# Dividing current to my electronics

Tags: power-divider

I have a 12v 15amp power supply, and I have 5 appliances.
I want to build this circuit in parallel, so voltage here is constant.(12v)So i'm not going to mention voltages.
The first appliance uses 10 amps.The 2nd uses 2 amps. And the 3rd, 4th, and 5th each use 1 amp. How would I distribute the current so that each appliance gets what is required?
I thought of a way, It would probably work theoretically but maybe not practically. In other words I'm not sure it'll work.
I thought of taking 15 wires, and soldering them to the positive terminal, do the same for the negative terminal. So right now each wire is carrying 1 amp.
Then, I would take 10 of these wires (10 positive and 10 negative of course) and connect them to my first appliance which uses 10 amps. Then connect 2 wires to my 2nd appliance, and 1 wire each to my 3rd, 4th, 5th appliances.
Will this work?
Thanks in advance, Mitch

Comment: Each appliance will take what it needs, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1 amps for appliances 1 thru 5 respectively. Just use 5 wires each of them large enough to handle the current to that load.

Comment: Google Kirchoffs current law and Kirchoffs voltage law.

Answer (score 1):

Each appliance will take what it needs, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1 amps for appliances 1 thru 5 respectively. Just use 5 wires each of them large enough to handle the current to that load.

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting loads in parallel to your power supply of (reasonably) constant voltage. This is the way most power distribution is done. Consider your home's electrical supply is 120 V or 230 V AC, depending where you live. Each lamp and power socket is wired in parallel from the same supply.

You can connect them in "star" configuration with each wired individually back to the incoming supply or you can wire them strung along on one cable provided the cable is heavy enough to carry the current for all the devices.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxxl4V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Power supply and loads with optional switches wired in parallel on one pair of conductors.*

The current which flows in each load will be *dependent on the load* not on the supply or the wiring (unless either is inadequate).